# Write information to local filein xamarin c# app

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, file, xamarin

I want to write string to file in same directory as my project in xamarin c# app.

```
if (!File.Exists("healthcare6copy.db"))
{
    File.Create("healthcare6copy.db");
}
```

It gives me unauthorized access exception. I call this code from simple class in my project.  I do this because I have database.db file as

```
 string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                        "healthcare6.db");
```

I need to retrieve that file information and write it to file locally on my PC.

Comment: You can’t write to the app bundle at runtime.  You need to use a path to a writable app folder using SpecialFolders, like you are doing in the 2nd snippet

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: Thats not exactly my case. I am able to write from local file to Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData. But how do I read that file back and open it on my computer?  @Jason

Comment: That is a very different question than what you actually asked.  Do you need every user to be able to do this, or only you as the developer?  IOS or Android?

Comment: @Jason only me as developer. Xamarin forms. Or at least just Android

Comment: Use adb to extract files from your Android device

Answer (score 0):

As Jason has pointed it out that the app bundle is signed and therefore is `read-only` at runtime.

You can copy a file that attached in `Resources` at app startup to a writeable folder, like the `LocalApplicationData` folder which is `INTERNAL_STORAGE/.local/share`. So you can use an `Environment.SpecialFolder` to reach this folder.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                        "healthcare6.txt");
File.Copy("healthcare6.txt", dbPath); // From Resource folder to LocalApplicationData folder
File.WriteAllText(dbPath, "write some test text");
```

For more details, you can refer to [Reading or Writing to files on internal storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#reading-or-writing-to-files-on-internal-storage) and [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows).

Comment: Thats not exactly my case. I am able to write from local file to Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData. But how do I read that file back and open it on my computer?

Comment: You may use `adb` to export the file from your mobile device to your local computer and then do the `write` operation to it.